# Update entire Excel table with OleDb

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, dataset, oledb

My excel simulation needs to be imported into C#, after which the table needs to be able to be refreshed. The simulation revolves around randomly generated numbers. The random numbers are the only columns that change, since I'm doing that manually. The surrounding columns should update with the random numbers. I have tried various things but no luck so far.

Also, as the code is now, the

```
adp.Update(excelDataSet);
```

command invokes the error "Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows." The table is only loaded into the gridview at all when it is commented out.

Here is my code atm. Thanks in advance.

```
            string fileName = @"C:\simulation.xlsx";
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;READONLY=FALSE\"";
            OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand selectCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from [SHEET1$]", con);             
            OleDbDataAdapter adp = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
            adp.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
            DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(excelDataSet);

            for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
            {
                excelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] = Math.Round(r.NextDouble(), 2);
                excelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][6] = Math.Round(r.NextDouble(), 2);
                excelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][8] = Math.Round(r.NextDouble(), 2);
            }
            adp.Update(excelDataSet);
            gridview.DataSource = excelDataSet.Tables[0];
            con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a line that build a [OleDbCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder.aspx)

```
....
OleDbDataAdapter adp = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
adp.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adp);
adp.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
....
```

This will create the `UpdateCommand` in the OleDbDataAdapter for you, (can be used also for the `InsertCommand` and `DeleteCommand`)